# Best practices when deploying Dask Cloudprovider EC2 cluster while allowing public access to Dashboard

Tags: amazon-ec2, dask, dask-distributed

I have the following workflow where I start a Dask Cloudprovider `EC2Cluster` with the following config:

```yaml
dask_cloudprovider:
  region: eu-central-1
  bootstrap: True
  instance_type: t3.small
  n_workers: 1
  docker_image: daskdev/dask:2022.10.0-py3.10
  security: False
  debug: True
  use_private_ip: False
  # other properties: region, instance_type, security_group, vpc, etc. omitted
```

This is supposed to start both my scheduler and my workers in docker on EC2 instances in the same VPC. The AWS security group has the following inbound rules:

| Port range | Source |
| --- | --- |
| 8786 - 8787 | [own group] |
| 8787 | [my ip] |

So, the workers and scheduler should be able to talk among themselves, and I should also be able to access the Scheduler Bokeh Dashboard from my IP only.

The important part is that the above security group rules only allow communication between the *private* IPs of the instances in the same security group, and do not allow traffic between the *public* IPs of the instances.

This is OK, since traffic between public IPs necessarily must be routed through an internet gateway and hence incurs bandwidth costs.

The problem is these network rules do not work as-is. My scheduler starts as follows:

```
Creating scheduler instance
Created instance i-09fe7442a8026db71 as dask-723b83ae-scheduler
Waiting for scheduler to run at <public scheduler IP>:8786
```

The IP that `dask-cloudprovider` advertises as the IP where the workers should connect is the *public* scheduler IP. Worker<->Scheduler traffic through public IP is not allowed as per my security group (and I wish to keep it so).

The only way that would allow the workers/schedulers to communicate in this setup that I've found is to set `use_private_ip: True`, but in that case my `EC2Cluster` startup hangs on trying to reach the scheduler at its private EC2 IP, which I obviously can't access from my own workstation.

I've seen that the 'recommended' approach is to deploy the `EC2Cluster` from **yet another** VM on e.g. EC2 in the same VPC, but I don't understand the upside of this when I could simply develop and then start it locally. It also adds another layer where I would have to get my code onto this separate VM (*and* install all requirements or rebuild an image every time).

What is the best way to accomplish my goal here?

Comment: Site note: I've posted this question on the [Dask discourse group](https://dask.discourse.group/t/how-to-pass-private-ip-of-scheduler-to-dask-worker-running-on-ec2/1259) as well in the hope of garnering some attention. I'll update either if/when I learn more.

Comment: I was able to achieve exactly what I want (worker-sched talking through private VPC only, scheduler dashboard accessible from my IP) by monkey-patching `dask_cloudprovider.aws.ec2#configure_vm` to return `instance['PublicDnsName']` instead of `instance['PublicIpAddress']`, since AWS domain names are resolved to the public IP when queried externally and private IP otherwise. Unfortunately this also means my workers must have public IPs (even though no traffic can be routed there). This is a super hacky workaround, however, and there must be a better way of achieving the same result...